# Migrations in ASP.NET Core code-first not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I used to be able to do migrations using this command

```
dotnet ef migrations add seedData  -p Persistence/ -s API/
```

But now I get an error:

[image]

I have looked online and I tried updating the `dotnet-ef` tool:

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef

Successfully updated
Tool 'dotnet-ef' was successfully updated from version '3.1.3' to version '3.1.6'.
```

I reference these packages in my project:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Can anyone suggest to me why my migrations are working anymore.
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any regular output or just the same error message, when running the command `dotnet ef`? Also, did you run the `dotnet ef migrations add` command in the same PowerShell console window as the `dotnet tool update` command?

Comment: Yes i tried it in powershell as admin and i still get the same error. I also tried dotnet ef --help and i get the same error message as above

Comment: Go through the [troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues). It looks pretty decent.

Comment: It was a runtime issue. Its strange because i did not update anything myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. Just answer your own question with the solution that worked for your, if it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my sdk runtime for the migrations to work.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1